# Database is not effected and in return I get primary key as value of zero

Tags: c#, linq

I want to insert these primary keys in my other table, or is there any other easy way to add multiple data at a time?

```
using(Dbcontext)
{
    list<dbTable> dbTbl = new list<dbTbl>();
    list<long> RetrunedPrimaryKeys = new list<long>();
    for(int i=0; i<datafromPresentationlayer.count;i++)
    {
      dltable tbl = new dbtable();
      tbl.name = datafromPresentationlayer[i].name;
      tbl.address = datafromPresentationlayer[i].address
      dbTbl.add(tbl);
    }
    Dbcontext.dbTable.InsertAllOnSubmit();
    for(int i=0; i< datafromPresentationLayer.count;i++)
    {
        RetrunedPrimaryKeys.add(dbTbl[i].primarkeycolumn); // here i get all the primary keys as zero and in database there is not a single entry of these record
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call SubmitChanges() method on DbContext, before you read returned values. SubmitChanges method writes data to database.